# Using LINQ, select first of each group, create new obj with specific columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to select the Id and Description from an EF table, but with distinct on Description.

I realize there's no `SelectFirst`, but I think this will help describe what I'm trying to do (I saw it suggested to use `GroupBy/SelectFirst` as a way of trying to apply Distinct to a specific column):

```
var results = _db.Certifications
.GroupBy(c => c.Description)
.SelectFirst(c => new SearchCriterion {Id = c.CertificationId, Name = c.Description});
```

`FirstOrDefault()` on the end doesn't work ("arguments cannot be inferred from the usage") and my properties (CertificationId/Description) aren't being recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, you have to use an aggregate on non grouped by properties. The code below, using `Max`, will return the largest `CertificationId` based on each distinct `description`. You can change that to `Min` to get smallest `CertificationId`.

```
var results = _db.Certifications
        .GroupBy(c => c.Description)
        .Select(c => new SearchCriterion {Id = c.Max(y => y.CertificationId), Name = c.Key});
```

Comment: Ah! So it knows which Id to use. Thanks!